# How to set loading image in Windows Metro Application

Tags: windows-8

Does anyone know how to change this loading image with any other picture (logo for example)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using XAML / C#*, you just need to replace /Assets/SplashScreen.png with a suitable image with a size of 620 x 300 px.

Alternatively, add the correct size image and update the manifest file to point at the correct image.

`* Javascript apps may well have the same locations, but I don't have access to VS right now to check.`